# Why weights array should have a certain dimension

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to understand a code written for linear regression which involves weights and biases. Although this question may seem trivial to you, I am nevertheless confused as to why W_init should have the dimensions of n_dim. Could someone please explain?

```
def optimize(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,
                learning_rate=0.01,epochs=200,
                display_n_epoch=25):
        n_dim = X_train.shape[1]
    
        np.random.seed(42)
        #Initializing Weights
        W_init = np.ones(shape=(n_dim))
        b_init = np.zeros(1)
```

Comment: Those weights will be multiplying the so-called features. E.g, for 2 features, the model assumes `y_hat_n = w1 * x_n_1 + w2 * x_n_2 + b` where `x_n_1` and `x_n_2` represents features values for *n*th sample. The aim roughly, for example, is to find `w_i`'s such that some metric over `y_n - y_hat_n` is minimized with those `w_i`s (and also `b` the bias). A concrete example could be: `y` that you're regressing is car price and `x1` is car's age and `x2` is how many doors it has. Say you have 125 car samples in your dataset; this 125 is `X.shape[0]` and `X.shape[1]` is 2.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes things clearer.